# this variable undefined when passed into callback function

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I am trying to take an OOP approach in javascript by following [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/) and the one on the [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). When I instantiate my function/class with the `new` keyword the graph renders correctly, however when a this variable is passed into a callback function it becomes `undefined`, I was wondering if there was a way around this?

Here is my code:

```
function lineBasedCharts (renderTo, chartType, deviceID, metricType, refreshCycle, title, subtitle, yAxis, tooltip) {
    this.mRenderTo = renderTo
    this.mRefreshCycle = refreshCycle
    this.mChartType = chartType
    this.mTitle = title
    this.mSubtitle = subtitle
    this.mYAxis = yAxis
    this.mTooltip = tooltip

    ...

    this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function (ch) {
        //use a callback function off the end of highcharts, for when the chart has fully loaded.
        AddSeries(ch, deviceID, metricType);

        if (ch.series[0].data.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(requestData, this.mRefreshCycle, ch, ch.series[0].data[ch.series[0].data.length - 1].x, deviceID, metricType, this.mRefreshCycle);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is how I instantiate my object

```
var chart = []
chart.push(new lineBasedCharts('lineChart', 'spline', 49, 'TEMP', 30000, 'temp', 'Temp in degrees', 'Temperature (°C)', '°C'))
```

`this.mRefreshCycle` seems to be become undefined when used in the callback function.

Comment: `this` is most likely referring to your created `Highcharts.chart` object. Create an alias of this (`_this = this`) and try use `_this.mRefreshCycle`

Comment: @SethMcClaine so I would create a new variable and assign this.mRefreshCycle to that variable, and then pass that variable into the callback?

Comment: Added an answer with the updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, I would remove the "this" identifier and use the parameter that is being passed in. They're the same value at this point anyway, as long as you haven't changed the value of mRefreshCycle at a later time. If you have a mutator that does this then you will need to tweak this slightly.

How about making lineBasedChart an actual object?

```
var LineBasedChart = function (renderTo, chartType, deviceID, metricType, refreshCycle, title, subtitle, yAxis, tooltip) {
    var self = this;
    this.mRenderTo = renderTo
    this.mRefreshCycle = refreshCycle
    this.mChartType = chartType
    this.mTitle = title
    this.mSubtitle = subtitle
    this.mYAxis = yAxis
    this.mTooltip = tooltip

    ...

    this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function (ch) {
        //use a callback function off the end of highcharts, for when the chart has fully loaded.
        AddSeries(ch, deviceID, metricType);

        if (ch.series[0].data.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(requestData, self.mRefreshCycle, ch, ch.series[0].data[ch.series[0].data.length - 1].x, deviceID, metricType, self.mRefreshCycle);
        }
    });

    /*Mutator to update refresh cycle value*/
    this.setRefreshCycle = function(refreshCycle) {
        this.mRefreshCycle = refreshCycle;
    }
}
```

This would be useful if you're creating multiple objects e.g.

```
var lineBasedChart1 = new LineBasedChart(...)
var lineBasedChart2 = new LineBasedChart(...)
```

You don't necessarily need to use a mutator you could just call on the property directly.

```
lineBasedChart1.mRefreshCycle = 500;
```

Comment: I plan on being able to change these values at runtime, which is why I have done it this way.  Do you know how I would go creating mutators for this change these variables

Comment: I would create an alias like Seth has in his answer

Comment: to create mutators would I just use lineBasedCharts.prototype.SetRefresh = function(newRefresh){} ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how you can change the value and have included an alias in my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `refreshCycle` as argument to `setTimeout` instead. It is always dangerous to use `this` since it changes meaning dependent upon context.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is most likely referring to your created `Highcharts.chart` object. Create an alias of `this (_this = this)` and try use `_this.mRefreshCycle`

```
function lineBasedCharts (renderTo, chartType, deviceID, metricType, refreshCycle, title, subtitle, yAxis, tooltip) {
    //Add alias for this
    _this = this;
    this.mRenderTo = renderTo
    this.mRefreshCycle = refreshCycle
    this.mChartType = chartType
    this.mTitle = title
    this.mSubtitle = subtitle
    this.mYAxis = yAxis
    this.mTooltip = tooltip

    ...

    this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function (ch) {
        //use a callback function off the end of highcharts, for when the chart has fully loaded.
        AddSeries(ch, deviceID, metricType);

        if (ch.series[0].data.length > 0) {
            //change how you refer to mRefreshCycle
            setTimeout(requestData, _this.mRefreshCycle, ch, ch.series[0].data[ch.series[0].data.length - 1].x, deviceID, metricType, this.mRefreshCycle);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of 'this' within the callback function is likely the "new Highcharts.Chart", not the "lineBasedChart" function.  It has no idea what mRefreshCycle is because it does not exist within the scope of the newly created object. You might be able to just remove the 'this' and take advantage of the closure mechanism.

Also, the "options" being passed to the "new Highcharts.Chart()" are undefined.

Sending this from my phone.   I apologize for lack of markdown. I will update the format of answer when I get a chance.